# Is there a way to make my viewpoint run faster?

Tags: animation, rigging

I have a character with about 1,000 bones.  It's not super complex, characters have a lot of bones right? lol  The bones have constraints.

I've been using bone layer add-on to hide the bones, but it doesn't seem to be working. When I pose, there's is a lag.  Interestingly, I have another character who is lightly rigged and if I hide the complex character, I can pose a lot faster.  So I'm pretty sure it's the 1k bone armaature giving blender a hard time.

Is there anyway I can optimize my workflow to make this faster or there is no way?  I'm already in Solid/Wireframe mode.  I'm not even using Evee viewpoint.  Is there anything I can turn off?

Comment: Have less bones?..

Comment: i am sorry to say, but i cannot really imagine why a character needs 1000 bones!? Can you elaborate a bit more why it needs 1000 bones? or show us the character?

Comment: Also if the mesh is high poly it probably slows down the viewport

Comment: Well, as said before - less bones would be a good start... what needs a thousand bones, a model of a myriapod where you move each leg individually? Even the myriapod itself doesn't really do that :D Less polys as well if you have a high poly mesh. Disabling the overlays also speeds up the viewport.

Comment: They're helper bones.  Most of them don't even deform, they're there to trigger shape keys or the movement of other bones.  I'm exaggerating when I say 1,000.. .Probably ~500ish.  

So if there are now way it.  I thought there might be a way to turn off bone calculations when they are hidden.  Because I do use a bone layer add-on which hides bones.  But I guess they're still animating hidden.  Strangely I found that it's only the armature, I have another character on a lighter armature and it animates smoothly.